# Синхронная обработка асинхронно накопленных данных. Теория.

Tags: callback, javascript, асинхронность

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, общий метод работы в следующем случае (и из той же категории):

Предположим, есть набор id объектов, хранящихся в локальной БД мобильного приложения.

```
var ids = [1, 3, 5].
```

Получать объект по его id я могу простым запросом к БД из транзакции:

```
for (var i in ids)
    transaction.executeSql( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '+i, [], self.querySuccess, self.errorCB );
```

И вот мне в коллбэк приходят вытащенные объекты, мне надо их все сохранить в какой-нибудь массив, и когда я получу все желаемые объекты, что-то с этим массивом сделать. Например, на сервер пульнуть.

Как я делаю: перед началом цикла запоминаю сколько объектов я должен получить из БД, в коллбэке веду счетчик пришедших объектов, и таким образом узнаю, когда я получил все объекты.

Вопрос: нормально ли это, или велосипед? Может есть другие методы для решения подобных задач?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async/), в ней есть множество методом, с помощью которых можно решить вашу проблему, например  [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async/)

```
async.map(
    ids, 
    function(item, callback){
        transaction.executeSql( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '+item, [], 
            function(result){
                // здесь наверно получаете результат выполнения запроса, его надо передать вторым параметром в callback
                callback(null/*error*/, result);
        });
    },
    function(err, resгlt){
        // в result будет окончательный результат 
    }
);
```

Comment: О, супер! Возьму на вооружение эту библиотеку. Глянул её код, он работает как я предположил в своем вопросе - все сводится к такому же счетчику (метод async.forEach если кто решит заглянуть). Но во всяком случае библиотека предоставляет универсальную и красивую обертку для решения, избавляет от изобретения велосипеда.
Спасибо!

Comment: >библиотека предоставляет универсальную и красивую обертку для решения, избавляет от изобретения велосипеда

автор библиотеки, когда-то сказал о ней примерно тоже самое

Comment: @Spectre спасибо что подменили :D